# How to handle `is deprecated. Deprecated in Java`?

Tags: android, kotlin, deprecation-warning

The code I want to use:

```kotlin
window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED)
```

There is [`FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams#flag_show_when_locked) that is deprecated in the API 27 and its alternative [`setShowWhenLocked`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/app/Activity#setshowwhenlocked) added in the API 27
How should I use it properly if the `minSdk` in my project is 21 and the targetSdk is 33?

I get the warning `is deprecated. Deprecated in Java`
Even if I handle it this way:

```kotlin
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 27) {
    setShowWhenLocked(true)
    setTurnScreenOn(true)
} else {
    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD or
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED or
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON)
}
```

I still get the warning. What is the right way to support both old and new API?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### TLDR

1.Use different code for different API versions.
2.Ignore/surpress this warning if you properly proccess all the API versions that your app is created for
3.If there is a new alternative that works for all the `API` levels - use it

### Example with the `FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED/setShowWhenLocked`

1. Use [`Build.VERSION.SDK_INT`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION#SDK_INT) in the condition to behave accordingly to the SDK_INT
2. Use `setshowwhenlocked` if `SDK_INT>=27` and `FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED` if `SDK_INT<27`
3. Surpress the warning

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 27) {
    setShowWhenLocked(true)
    setTurnScreenOn(true)
} else {
    @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD or
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED or
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON)
}
```

### But why do we have to surpsess the warning?

The warning exists only because **`@Deprecated` APIs do not have any metadata that would indicate which SDK they were deprecated in.** as you can see in [this issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/228611948).
We can surpress the error because we have properly processed both old api (5-27) and new api (27>)

### Warning

Do not surpress these warnings if the code is not properly processed by using if conditions where the right API is used.

### Example how you must not do

```
@Suppress("DEPRECATION")
window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD or
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED or
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON)
```

Your minSdk is 21 and targetSdk is 33
This code will work on devices with 5-27 API (Android 5 - Android 8.1) but will not work on new devices. You must properly handle both conditions.

### Example with the `Vibrator`

The old way to get the vibrator

```
context.getSystemService(VIBRATOR_SERVICE) as Vibrator
```

The new way to get the vibrator

```
val vibrator = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 31) {
    val vibratorManager =
        context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_MANAGER_SERVICE) as VibratorManager
    vibratorManager.defaultVibrator
} else {
    @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
    context.getSystemService(VIBRATOR_SERVICE) as Vibrator
}
Will show you the warning `'VIBRATOR_SERVICE: String' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java`. Go to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/content/Context#vibrator_service) and see that this constant can be used in the API 1-31 so we must. And in both IDE and documentation there is the info about the alternative: `Deprecated: Use android.os.VibratorManager to retrieve the default system vibrator.`. As you can see the [VibrationManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/os/VibratorManager) is added in the API 31 therefore we must write the different code for different sdk versions
```

### If an alternative is backwards compatible

If an alternative is backwards compatible you can just use it instead of the old way

##### Example

If you inherit `AppCompatActivity` in your activity:

```
class SaveMyLifeActivity : AppCompatActivity()
```

You can meet the warning `startActivityForResult(Intent!, Int): Unit' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java` if you call `startActivityForResult`:

```
val intent = Intent(this, SaveMyLifeActivity::class.java)
startActivityForResult(intent, 0)
```

You can press Alt+Q (Default keybind) to see the `Context info`(it is called this way in the AndroidStudio is you check your keymap) or [use the website do see the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/activity/ComponentActivity#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent,int,android.os.Bundle))
[image: Context info]
Take a look to the words that this method is deprecated and you must use [`registerForActivityResult`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/activity/ComponentActivity#registerForActivityResult(androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContract%3CI,O%3E,androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultCallback%3CO%3E)) instead. This method can be called in any version right now, there are no `Added/Deprecated` "section" in the documentation.

**Question:** How have you found this documentation? I google `AppCombatActivity startActivityForResult` and come to [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/appcompat/app/AppCompatActivity) documentation. There is no word about `startActivityForResult`.
**Answer:** Open the context info about this method in the IDE (Alt+Q) and look at the bottom of the `Context info` [image: Context info]. There is a class name where this method is located in (`ComponentActivity`). You have to google `ComponentActivity startActivityForResult` instead of `AppCombatActivity startActivityForResult`