# getApplicationInfo(String,int) deprecated, What is the alternative?

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation, deprecation-warning, android-tiramisu

I have upgraded targetSdkVersion and compileSdkVersion to 33.

Now getting warning getApplicationInfo(String,int) is deprecated.

It is suggested to use use getApplicationInfo(java.lang.String, android.content.pm.PackageManager.ApplicationInfoFlags) instead. Anyone can help me to use the updated method.

Example:

```
@SuppressLint("HardwareIds")
    public void initDbx(){
        try {
            ApplicationInfo app = activity.getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(activity.getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
            dbx.game_id      = String.valueOf(app.metaData.getInt("main_id"));
            dbx.game_name    = activity.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name);
            dbx.package_name = activity.getApplication().getPackageName();
            dbx.user_id      = Settings.Secure.getString(activity.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
            dbx.check_net    = isConnectionAvailable();
            //dbx.getUserInfos(activity);
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

So, I did this:

```
    @SuppressLint("HardwareIds")
    public void initDbx(){
        try {
//            ApplicationInfo app = activity.getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(activity.getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);

            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
                ApplicationInfo app = activity.getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(activity.getPackageName(), PackageManager.ApplicationInfoFlags.of(0));
            }else{
                ApplicationInfo app = activity.getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(activity.getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
            }
            
            dbx.game_id      = String.valueOf(app.metaData.getInt("main_id"));
            dbx.game_name    = activity.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name);
            dbx.package_name = activity.getApplication().getPackageName();
            dbx.user_id      = Settings.Secure.getString(activity.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
            dbx.check_net    = isConnectionAvailable();
            //dbx.getUserInfos(activity);
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Get the error (Cannot resolve symbol 'app')

```
            dbx.game_id      = String.valueOf(app.metaData.getInt("main_id"));
```

I created local variable 'app':

```
            PackageItemInfo app;
            dbx.game_id      = String.valueOf(app.metaData.getInt("main_id"));
```

Get the error (Variable 'app' might not have been initialized)

I initialize the variable; I tried both:

```
            PackageItemInfo app = null;
            dbx.game_id      = String.valueOf(app.metaData.getInt("main_id"));
```

and:

```
            PackageItemInfo app = new PackageItemInfo();
            dbx.game_id      = String.valueOf(app.metaData.getInt("main_id"));
```

But I kept getting the same warning, and I couldn't even run the app in the emulator this time.

Answer (score 8):

[`getApplicationInfo(String packageName,int flags)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager#getApplicationInfo(java.lang.String,%20int)) have been deprecated in Android Api 33.
We need to use [`getApplicationInfo(java.lang.String,android.content.pm.PackageManager.ApplicationInfoFlags)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager#getApplicationInfo(java.lang.String,%20android.content.pm.PackageManager.ApplicationInfoFlags))

```
  if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
      ApplicationInfo app = activity.getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(activity.getPackageName(), PackageManager.ApplicationInfoFlags.of(0));
  }else{
      ApplicationInfo app = activity.getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(activity.getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
  }
```

You can pass either zero or combinations of other component info flags in `ApplicationInfoFlags`. More details in [ApplicationInfoFlags](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.ApplicationInfoFlags)

**Edited:** Completed initDbx() method

```
 public void initDbx(){
        try {
            ApplicationInfo app;
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
                app = activity.getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(activity.getPackageName(), PackageManager.ApplicationInfoFlags.of(0));
            }else{
                 app = activity.getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(activity.getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
            }

            dbx.game_id      = String.valueOf(app.metaData.getInt("main_id"));
            dbx.game_name    = activity.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name);
            dbx.package_name = activity.getApplication().getPackageName();
            dbx.user_id      = Settings.Secure.getString(activity.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
            dbx.check_net    = isConnectionAvailable();
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Nitish, I've edited my question, can you check it out?

Comment: @Upside-Down , make `ApplicationInfo app` a global variable , current it's local inside `if-else`

Comment: How do I do that Did you mean to create field 'app' in UtilsManager Like this: private PackageItemInfo app; Because this prevented the app from launching in the emulator

Comment: Why would that prevent app from launching? . Anyways you can just make it outside the `if else` statement so that is accessible out of the conditions. Have edited my answer

Comment: I was making it after the `if-else ` its launching now but I'm still getting the deprecation warning.

Comment: It doesn't show at my system, can you please share more details on this,

Comment: like what? ask me. This java file is about 200 lines long, all I know is that I keep getting this warning as long as I don't completely get rid of this one; `app = activity.getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(activity.getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);`

Comment: [handle-is-deprecated-deprecated-in-java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74506278/how-to-handle-is-deprecated-deprecated-in-java) this could be most probable reason why warning is still showing

Answer (score 0):

I've faced problems when tried to use the new api, the returned metaData was null.

Before deprecation I used:

```
val appInfo = activity.getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(activity.getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
val metaData : Bundle = app.metaData //Returned null!
```

But when try to use the new api with `PackageManager.ApplicationInfoFlags.of(0)` the metaData was null!
So instead I had to use it like this:

```
packageManager.getApplicationInfo(packageName, PackageManager.ApplicationInfoFlags.of(GET_META_DATA.toLong()))
```

Then returned metaData was ok.